# NetMQ - polling a dealer socket and timeout

Tags: asynchronous, timeout, zeromq, netmq

i'am using a DEALER-ROUTER pattern to make a sort of load balancing between client(s) and workers.

I'am wondering how to set a timeout between the client and the server to avoid infinite waits.

I tried to set the timeout parameter of the TryReceiveMultipartMessage method but it has no effect. I forced my server to reply after 10s and even setting a timeout to 1s I recieve the response.

My client code is :

```
    public void Main(string Args[])
    {
        using(ctx = NetMQContext.Create())
        {
            using(client = ctx.CreateDealerSocket())
            {
                client.Options.Identity = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                client.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");
                client.ReceiveReady += Client_ReceiveReady;
                poller.AddSocket(client);
                poller.PollTillCancelled();
            }
    }


    void Client_ReceiveReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
    {
        NetMQMessage clientMessage = new NetMQMessage();
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        if (e.Socket.TryReceiveMultipartMessage(timeout, ref clientMessage))
        {
            ...
        }

    }
```

How can I set a Timeout on recieving message from a DEALER socket?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you are using poller you will get notified when a message is ready to be received, so there is no impact for using timeout. I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, or what exactly is the question. Using the poller you don't have to wait indefinitely, poller will raise the event when message is ready to be received.

Comment: Ok. I realized the non-sense of my question. In a context of polling I don't have to wait because it's asynchronous. I was wrongly thinking that the async Query on my dealer socket will create a new socket. 

My bad ; )